# Dotnet EF Core builds the project and hangs

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, debian-buster

[image]

I'm trying to scaffold a single table from an existing database. After 'Build Succeeded' the process hangs without showing any further progress. I can see the process running, holding at ~ 12% CPU. I'm running Debian 10.

The server is running on a VirtualBox VM. I confirmed the database is accessible using DBeaver. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this, because I'm not getting any kind of error message.

I updated login auditing on the SQL server to collect both failed and successful logins. When I connect from something like DBeaver, I see successful logins for the database account. I don't see any logs recorded when I run the dotnet ef scaffold command.

I started Wireshark, and I do see traffic between my computer and the VM on port 1433. There is a TDS7 pre-login message, a bunch of acknowledgements, and then keep-alive requests and acknowledgements. So I know network connectivity is not an issue. It's like the dotnet ef command is just sitting and waiting for the database to respond.

I completed the same steps on a Mac laptop, and was able to scaffold the models without any issues.

Comment: Hi, did you figure out a solution in the meantime?

Comment: @B12Toaster Unfortunately no. I haven't had much time to do so. Plus, without any kind of error message, it's hard to determine where to begin. It's probably something with my desktop set up. If you or anyone has suggestions, I'd be appreciative.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, unfortunately no, I am also stuck without a solution. After 'Build Succeeded' the process just hangs without showing any further progress, I added the `--verbose` flag and it gives some additional infos but nothing useful. My solution so far was to create the new scaffolding tables manually by hand :(

Comment: I've just hit the same issue here.